# Jquery Mobile Displaying External Web Site In A Dialog

Tags: jquery, mobile

Anyone know of a few methods to handle opening an external site (google.com) inside of a jquery mobile dialog. Everything is so new right now resources and examples are limited.

Thanks!

I have a feeling it's done a bit differently then a normal jquery iframe load. This is partially from the documentation.

`$.mobile.loadPage( "site/page" )`

Comment: To answer myself. Iframes don't work at all and isn't a viable option in jqm

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate page within my own jQuery Mobile site, and within that page I included an iFrame with width="100%".  Then I linked to that page using data-rel="dialog" within the anchor of the link.  This produced the desired effect.  A pop-up dialog within jQuery containing a local page which itself contained an iframe to a page on a totally separate domain name.  It worked flawlessly.  When the other domain was a jQuery Mobile site, it even LOOKED flawless!

Comment: If you have an example of this on jsfiddle or such I would love to see it in action.